# Can you add buttons to navigation bars through storyboard?

Tags: ios

At the moment, I've been adding navigation buttons like follows:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                                          style:self.editButtonItem.style 
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
```

It seems a bit silly to not add them through storyboard, but I can't find a way to do so.  Is there one that I'm missing?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can just drag out a Bar Button Item and drop it on the right end of the view controller's navigation bar:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, what did you use to do that? It's the FUTURE!

Comment: Snapz Pro X to record the screen (tho you can do it with QuickTime Player in Lion), then QuickTime Player 7 to export the movie as image files, then [GIFFun](http://www.stone.com/GIFfun/) to convert the image files to an animated GIF.

Comment: That works for adding one left item bar, what if I need to add more items at the left of the navigation bar?

Comment: If you want to create animated gif from screen capture then you can capture a portion of the screen using QuickTime and then convert the file using this web site: http://www.zamzar.com

Comment: These days I use (and recommend) [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).  It's free and saves directly to animated GIF.

Comment: And for adding **multiple** buttons on either side, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897978/cant-assign-multiple-buttons-to-uinavigationitem-when-using-storyboard-with-ios

Comment: Licecap software records directly your screen to GIF without any conversion, just choose your record size area, choose your frame per seconds, and run it !

Comment: I've been using LICEcap for the last couple of years, unless I need to record the menu bar.

Answer (score 30):

As of Xcode 6, it looks like the navigation item on the navigation bar is no longer created automatically.

You'll need to drag out a Navigation Item onto the navigation bar first before you can drag out a Bar Button Item (as detailed in Rob's answer) to add to the navigation item.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Was wondering where on earth Navigation bar lol.

Comment: thank you for this - this is incredibly confusing. To reference Rob's .gif, you drag a "navigation item" onto the same area as he shows dragging the bar button item. Then, you drag the bar button item there afterwards.