# Multiple buttons in iOS Navigation Bar via Interface Builder?

Tags: ios

I understand that iOS 5 added the capability of setting multiple right and left buttons, but can this be done through Interface Builder?  Whenever I attempt to drag a bar button item to the navigation bar it only allows one on the right and one on the left.

Comment: Please, check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32617060/3052059

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update: Xcode 7 add multi buttons support.

Just drag bar button items to navigation bar, you may need add a navigation item first if the view controller don't have one.

[image: demo]

---

You can drag a UIView to the navigation bar, then add two UIButton to that view.

Cannot add two UIBarButtonItem througn interface builder directly. But you can make it through code. Like `[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:animated:]`.

Comment: Can you edit to explain how to do this in Xcode 7/8 ? Thanks

Comment: @BradThomas I add a gif demo above.

Comment: your explanation "you may need add a navigation item first if the view controller don't have one."  saved my day.