# Add multiple buttons to navigation bar in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I wonder if this can be achieved using **Storyboard IB**:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barButton1, barButton2]`

**EDITED:**

The purpose is to preserve the benefits of using storyboard and if it's possible *without using any lines of code*.

**EDIT #2:**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929183/623396) I experimented and saw that it is possible to link the Title View property of the Navigation Item to a Toolbar
[image]

but it looks to me like a *hack* (and I might want to preserve the Title as well):

[image]

Any better idea?

Comment: I did try, but it worked for **one button only**.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897978/cant-assign-multiple-buttons-to-uinavigationitem-when-using-storyboard-with-ios

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20419513/623396

Answer (score 9):

There a way to add a view to navigationItem. 
Than add buttons or labels you need to the view.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can use below code :

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnShare = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.backbtn];
UIBarButtonItem *btnRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.testbutton2];   
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnShare,btnRefresh, nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

1 -> Drag and drop Bar Button Item in navigation bar and in latest xcode you can direclty place more than one items in navigation bar either on left or right side

[image: see this for example]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `UIToolbar` containing all yours buttons:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
// ... set toolbars' frame, initialize buttons, etc;
[toolbar setItems:@[barButton1, barButton2] animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
```

Or you could use `setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:` and `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:`

Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Your buttons in storyboard edit/style them as you like then create their outlets and add them as top level objects and then add them at run time at viewDidLoad using [navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:] and [navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:... Hope that Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add multiple button on toolbar . Adding multiple button on navigation bar is not a good idea . if you want add multiple button on toolbar using storyboard . this video link might help you to make a scrollable toolbar with multiple button 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nYM8EfTpRw

Comment: I don't think is such a bad idea, Apple does it in their own appstore app.

Comment: @user623396 yes because Apple encourages the use storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them from the code, **in Swift** you can do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ....
    let ubRefresh = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: "refreshManually")
    let ubMyIcon = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "MyIcon"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "myAction")
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([ubMyIcon, ubRefresh], animated: true)

}
```