# Bar button item icon size and width

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

[image]

I have a navigation bar with 3 bar button items. But i wonder why i have a huge space between first two icons ? And why default share icon less then my custom icons. My custom icons have size 29x29.

[image]

Comment: look at the view debugger. You will find the reason.

Comment: pls read the documentation regarding the icons and image sizes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: look at the view debugger while u run the app. Dont look at the debug console. Look at view debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to adjust space between two UIBarButtonItem in rightBarButtonItems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741824/how-to-adjust-space-between-two-uibarbuttonitem-in-rightbarbuttonitems)

Comment: @Arti, let me know if updated answer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: for navigation bar, you simply need to place all three items in one of the two (Left Bar Button Items) or the (Right Bar Button Items) as follows:

[image]

and it should look like this:

[image]

As for tool bar items:

What you need to do is put a flexible space bar button between your buttons like so:

[image]

then it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I have a navigation bar at top

Comment: OP is using Navigation bar.

Comment: @Arti, I updated my answer for navigation bar. Check it out.