# Remove UINavigationBar back button extra padding?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I've removed the back button's text by manually setting it to " " on each navigation item, however there is still extra padding between the button and the navigation item's title for no reason.
[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of this annoying spacing?
In a few real case scenarios in my app, the title does concatenate as it gets slightly too long, even though it wouldn't need to if that space were not there.

Comment: can you show me your code?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741824/how-to-adjust-space-between-two-uibarbuttonitem-in-rightbarbuttonitems/22742322#22742322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let arrayViews = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)
    if let itemView = arrayViews?[1] {
        for lbl in itemView.subviews {
            lbl.frame = CGRect(x: -25, y: lbl.frame.origin.y, width: lbl.frame.size.width, height: lbl.frame.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` which uses `popToViewController` to go back to the previous item on your stack. That way, you can manually set the frame of your custom back button.