# BarButtonItem malformed after switch to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibarbuttonitem, swift4

After upgrading to Swift 4, the code I used to add a custom `UIBarButtonItem` no longer works, and instead, squeezes the image in a peculiar fashion:

[image]

```
  // In viewDidLayoutSubviews
  if let backButton = Utils.createBackButton(color: .white, target: self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.backPressed)) {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        print("navigation button width", backButton)
    }

// In Utils.swift
class func createBackButton(color: BackArrowColors, target: UIViewController, selector: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem? {
    var backImage = UIImage()
    if color == .white {
        backImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow-white.png")!
    } else if color == .black {
        backImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow-black.png")!
    } else {
        return nil
    }

    let backButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
    backButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    backButton.setImage(backImage, for: .normal)
    backButton.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 10)
    let leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    return leftBarButtonItem
}
```

It seems the frame is correct, in the console I get the following console message:

```
navigation button width <UIBarButtonItem: 0x7fb3d7c0d010> view=<UIButton: 0x7fb3d7c20ae0; frame = (0 0; 35 35); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x60c000238b40>>
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with current iOS 11 release. UIBarButton items now uses constraints instead of the earlier frame approach.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677006/2570153) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677018/ios-11-uinavigationbar-bar-button-items-alignment) for solution or more explanation.

And [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320711/2570153) helps with the new implementation.

Comment: Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247451/ios-11-uibarbuttonitem-images-not-sizing/46320711#46320711 solved it for me!

Comment: That's Awesome!