# Swift how to distance two rightbar button items

Tags: swift, toolbar

I'm going to get straight to the point. The below code adds two bar button items without a problem, however I was wondering how I can put a distance between these two bar button items? They are too close to each other, that's why I'm looking for a way to manually set their distance to each other. I'd appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

```
let btnPlus = UIBarButtonItem()
        btnPlus.title = "+"

    btnPlus.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)!], for: .normal)
    btnPlus.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)!], for: .selected)
    btnPlus.target = self
    btnPlus.action = #selector(OnbtnPlusTouched)
    //btnPlus.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)!], for: UIControlState.normal)

    let btnRating = UIBarButtonItem()
    btnRating.title = "Oy Ver"

    btnRating.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)!], for: .normal)
    btnRating.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)!], for: .selected)
    btnRating.target = self
    btnRating.action = #selector(OnbtnPlusTouched)
    //btnPlus.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)!], for: UIControlState.normal)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [btnPlus, btnRating]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798343/4417447 Check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UIBarButtonItem` with a fixed space or a flexible space:

```
let btnPlus = UIBarButtonItem()
let btnRating = UIBarButtonItem()
let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 15

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [btnPlus, fixedSpace, btnRating]
```

There is also the possibility to use `.flexibleSpace`.