# adding popover to programmatically added UIBarButtonItem and adding images to the same popover Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, uipopovercontroller

From past few days i am trying to generate a popover for programmatically added UIBarButtonItem but i couldn't succeed. Added to this, i even want this popover to be presented with few images sequentially which are clickable. The following is the code of how i generated a UIBarButtonItem programmatically

```
func imagerendering(){
    let barbuttonimage = UIImage(named: "app")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: barbuttonimage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button1

    let attachButtonImage = UIImage(named: "icon-Attach")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    let attachButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: attachButtonImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([menuButton,attachButton], animated: true)

    let fixedSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    fixedSpace.width = 5.0
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [menuButton, fixedSpace, attachButton]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 16)!]
}
```

I have presented my desired output in an image as a link below. please go through it and let me know whether what i am desiring is possible or not.

[desired output image](http://s30.postimg.org/c194qp3jl/desiredoutput.png)

Comment: Yes it is possible. Tell me are you able to do a simple popover?

Comment: @iRealMe i know how to present it using storyboard but programmatically i am not sure.. have you gone through the image...? within the popover i need to present images sequentially and these images in-turn will have a action to perform

Comment: Ok..and from where those image will come?

Comment: just like in tableview we can add images right .. and program it. In the same way i want to do it please go through the link [example image] (http://s16.postimg.org/4zri7xc6d/exampleimage.png )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an extra bar item on navigation bar using storyboard, you can refer [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897978/cant-assign-multiple-buttons-to-uinavigationitem-when-using-storyboard-with-ios/20419513#20419513)

After that, set a popover from storyboard(you know it well as you said) and then put required buttons with actions in your popop view. You can set image for a button instead of title text.

Comment: as mentioned earlier this UIBarButtonItem has been created programmatically there is no instance in the story board

Comment: Oh ok. Once I tried to popup programmatically but I could not. So all you have to try is a popup from the code only then rest of things can be proceed

Comment: There may be alternate ways, if you try to find it

Comment: here is a sample of my storyboard..  [storyboard image] (http://s1.postimg.org/neiwsgzb3/storyboard.png) go through it and let me know how should i proceed further

Comment: Ah,why are you creating your bar button from the code only?

Comment: Yes I am getting your problem but tell me is it compulsory to create it from code?

Comment: I have created it because  I am unable  to add another barbutton  to the navigation  bar. ... if at all  I am adding  it it's just replacing  the  other one....

Comment: There are solutions of it..you may try! see the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20419513/3734028

Comment: that done the trick i have gone through the first one in the link

Comment: I have edited my answer for that useful link, please upvote!

Comment: sorry i can't upvote it as i don't have enough reputation.... i haven't got a clue of upvoting of another answer

Comment: How come this is the accepted answer? The question explicitly say that the button is added programatically, yet the accepted answer says how to solve the problem using storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) library. It gives you the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: thank you... for your response i achieved it through this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897978/cant-assign-multiple-buttons-to-uinavigationitem-when-using-storyboard-with-ios/20419513#20419513)