# Using the same barButtonItems and toolBarItems for all view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I've created my toolBar and navigationBar and added the respective items to it. I'm still new to coding but its my understanding that UINavigationController only displays the navBar and toolBar for the viewController in the top of the seque. I'm doing this without storyboards and in swift.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing, your question provides very little information about your issue.

Comment: I'm lost as to where to begin. I've connected to view controllers to buttons on my toolbar and I want those to have the same navigation bar and toolbar bar with the buttons in them

Comment: You can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273559/2768604

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, but unfortunately most of the documentation for help is with storyboards. I've seen a ton of videos and read every stackoverflow question and I'm still lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more than one bar button items to `UINavigationBar` programatically, you can do that like

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnShare = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share)];
UIBarButtonItem *btnRefresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnShare, btnRefresh, nil]];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks but i've already added the buttons to both bars. In my bottom bar i have two UIBarbutton items connected to two other view controllers. I cant seem to figure out how to pass the UINavigation bar with the same buttons and the UIToolBar with the same buttons over. Also if possible i code in swift but objective c is fine too