# Bar Button Navigation Controller is hidden Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to add a bar button in a navigation controller, but when I put the button, it looks like it is behind the navigation controller. Someone knows what happens?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: u can create custom navigation bar button items

Comment: What is the other Item for in the right button items ?

Comment: @Nitish it is just a test button

Comment: Add a Flexible space item as well in between the two.

Comment: I did it, I had two navigator controllers so I just delete one and it's works. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create it programmatically u can try this in ur view did load method

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton


let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.myLeftSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
//Mark - Call functions
func myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!)
{
    print("myRightSideBarButtonItemTapped")
}

func myLeftSideBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!)
{
    print("myLeftSideBarButtonItemTapped")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273204/can-you-add-buttons-to-navigation-bars-through-storyboard OR here is the answer on stackoverflow to create it by using storboard

Comment: It works now, it was that I had two navigation controller. Thanks for your suggestions.